# How to avoid errors while parsing through array in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, foreach

I am trying to migrate user data from a Drupal database to Wordpress. I'm trying to parse through a data column from Drupal and reorganize it so I can import it where I need to in the Wordpress database. The data column in Drupal is a serialized string:

`a:12:{s:23:"profile_membership_type";s:4:"Full";s:21:"ms_membership_add_new";s:0:"";s:18:"ms_membership_mpid";s:0:"";s:25:"ms_membership_amount_paid";s:0:"";s:32:"ms_membership_transaction_number";s:0:"";s:30:"ms_membership_current_payments";i:1;s:26:"ms_membership_max_payments";s:0:"";s:24:"ms_membership_start_date";a:3:{s:4:"year";s:4:"2014";s:5:"month";s:1:"2";s:3:"day";s:2:"13";}s:27:"ms_membership_should_expire";b:0;s:24:"ms_membership_expiration";a:3:{s:4:"year";s:4:"2014";s:5:"month";s:1:"2";s:3:"day";s:2:"13";}s:20:"ms_membership_status";i:3;s:7:"contact";i:1;}`

I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

This is my code thus far:

```
$fixed = preg_replace_callback(
   '/s:([0-9]+):\"(.*?)\";/',
   function ($matches) { return "s:".strlen($matches[2]).':"'.$matches[2].'";';     },
        $data
   );
$original_array = unserialize($fixed);

foreach ($original_array as $key => $value) {
   echo $value['profile_membership_type'];
};
```

Comment: when you do not need $key, just use `foreach (array_expression as $value)`

Comment: Check if it's an array before iterating?

Comment: All the answers are attempting to fix a bad hack. The real question is why on earth are you doing this?

Comment: There is something fishy going on here...why are you manipulating serialised data with regular expressions? What prevents you from just unserialising the original untouched data and manipulate the generated data structure instead?

Comment: I am migrating user data from a Drupal database to Wordpress. I'm trying to parse through a data column from Drupal and reorganize it so I can import it where I need to in the Wordpress database. the data column in Drupal is a serialized string.

Comment: Exactly, so just use `$niceStructuredNaitivePhpObject = unserialize($datastring);` and traverse the result

Comment: You even use `unserialize` on you regex produced string??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check with if condition before iteration

```
if(is_array($original_array) && !empty($original_array)){
    foreach ($original_array as $key => $value) {
       echo $value['profile_membership_type'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me using it directly after unserializing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast to an `array`.

```
foreach ( (array) $original_array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['profile_membership_type'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check to see if the variable you're iterating through is an array;

```
if(isset($original_array) && is_array($original_array)) {
    foreach ( $original_array as $key => $value) {
       echo $value['profile_membership_type'];
    }
}
```

Edited to include a check to ensure the variable exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have a php serialized string.

I presume the leading `f` in your question is a typo, as the rest is a valid serialized array:

```
$array = unserialize('a:12:{s:23:"profile_membership_type";s:4:"Full";s:21:"ms_membership_add_new";s:0:"";s:18:"ms_membership_mpid";s:0:"";s:25:"ms_membership_amount_paid";s:0:"";s:32:"ms_membership_transaction_number";s:0:"";s:30:"ms_membership_current_payments";i:1;s:26:"ms_membership_max_payments";s:0:"";s:24:"ms_membership_start_date";a:3:{s:4:"year";s:4:"2014";s:5:"month";s:1:"2";s:3:"day";s:2:"13";}s:27:"ms_membership_should_expire";b:0;s:24:"ms_membership_expiration";a:3:{s:4:"year";s:4:"2014";s:5:"month";s:1:"2";s:3:"day";s:2:"13";}s:20:"ms_membership_status";i:3;s:7:"contact";i:1;}');

var_dump($array);
/*
array (size=12)
  'profile_membership_type' => string 'Full' (length=4)
  'ms_membership_add_new' => string '' (length=0)
  'ms_membership_mpid' => string '' (length=0)
  'ms_membership_amount_paid' => string '' (length=0)
  'ms_membership_transaction_number' => string '' (length=0)
  'ms_membership_current_payments' => int 1
  'ms_membership_max_payments' => string '' (length=0)
  'ms_membership_start_date' => 
    array (size=3)
      'year' => string '2014' (length=4)
      'month' => string '2' (length=1)
      'day' => string '13' (length=2)
  'ms_membership_should_expire' => boolean false
  'ms_membership_expiration' => 
    array (size=3)
      'year' => string '2014' (length=4)
      'month' => string '2' (length=1)
      'day' => string '13' (length=2)
  'ms_membership_status' => int 3
  'contact' => int 1
*/
```

Note that there is only a single `profile_membership_type` element, so there is no need to loop:

```
echo $array['profile_membership_type']; // Full
```